# How to update the values of probabilities of Hidden Markov Model in c#?

Tags: c#, hidden-markov-models, accord.net

In Accord.NET(c#) how can I set new values of probabilities in the model?
I used the property "Probabilities" in HiddenMarkovModel< TDistribution> Class to get the log-initial probabilities log(pi) for the model and to set new probabilities in the model.
But you know, it is obsolete now.　So I use "LogInitial" instead, But it can only get the values, not set. Could you tell me the method to set new probabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the property is "get-only", you can still set the elements of the array at the LogInitial property to any value you would like.

If you need to set the probabilities, just use:

```
hmm.LogInitial[0] = value_you_would_like;
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [extension method SetTo(array)](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Math_Matrix_SetTo__1_3.htm), such that you could configure the values of that property using, for example:

```
hmm.LogInitial.SetTo(new [] { 0.1, 0.5, 0.4 });
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your information! I will try it.